# KeyError: 'object'

Tags: python, request, facebook-api, бот

Сел разбираться с ботом для FB. Так как не сталкивался с ботами решил посмотреть проекты людей на гите. Ссылка на оригинал -> https://github.com/hartleybrody/fb-messenger-bot/ Но не могу его запустить. Все метки проставил, сделал себе сервер на ngrok. Больше всего интересует последняя строчка в методе send_message(). У меня всё "крашится" на ней(. Может кто встречался с такой проблемой? Вот мой код:

```
    if data["object"] == "page":
    print(data)
    for entry in data["entry"]:

        for messaging_event in entry["messaging"]:

            if messaging_event.get("message"):  # someone sent us a message

                sender_id = messaging_event["sender"]["id"]        # the facebook ID of the person sending you the message
                recipient_id = messaging_event["recipient"]["id"]  # the recipient's ID, which should be your page's facebook ID
                message_text = messaging_event["message"]["text"]  # the message's text
                print(message_text)
                params = {
                    "access_token": "EAAGN0FlxPLYBAMZCCYt..."
                }
                headers = {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
                data_to_cli = json.dumps({
                    "recipient": {
                        "id": sender_id #recipient_id
                    },
                    "message": {
                        "text": 'ok, got it!'
                    }
                })
                print(data_to_cli)
                requests.post("https://e74a75b9.ngrok.io", params=params, headers=headers, data=data_to_cli)
```

Ошибка полностью

```
"POST /?access_token=EAAGN0FlxPLYBAMZCCYt...eb6ZBP HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FBbot\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FBbot\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FBbot\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FBbot\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FBbot\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FBbot\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FBbot\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FBbot\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FBbot\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FBbot\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка\app.py", line 31, in webhook
    if data["object"] == "page":
KeyError: 'object'
```

Ошибка идёт на строчке requests.post.

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте к вопросу.

Comment: Похоже на то, что в приходящем вэбхуку json'е нет ключа "page".

Comment: в том и прикол, что есть) я принтил все json`ы (на входе и на выходе) - всё формируется как надо.